# SLF4J Logback LoggerContext Conflicts

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, slf4j

I am working on deploying a spring boot executable jar for my application. Im using SLF4J logging, and when I build and run inside of IntelliJ I have no issues.

However, when I try to run the .jar, from the command line I get a **LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath** exception.

It complains about the **slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar** in two places `/opt/mapr/lib/` and `/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/`.

If i remove the jar from both places and run my app:

`java -cp $(mapr classpath):MapRProducerApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher`

it will then fail startup due to **SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".**

I dont understand why it would fail saying faild to load the slf4j class when my apps .jar is built with that dependency through

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

In IntelliJ, I am bringing in all external dependencies that exist inside the `/opt/mapr/lib` folder, which includes the **slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar**, but IntelliJ does not give the Logback LoggerContext error.

To recap here:

- Building and running the jar on its own works, but will fail because it needs dependencies that exist inside the `mapr classpath`.
- Running the jar with the `mapr classpath` fails because of the slf4j jar inside /opt/mapr/lib.
- Removing that jar leads to another failure about a slf4j jar in /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/.
- Removing that jar then fails the app because it now cannot find any slf4j binding.

Is there something im missing? Do I need to package my app a certain way so it does not include the SLF4J dependency?

Comment: 1) Are you building a war file or jar file? 2) please post your pom.xml in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear about your `<dependencies>` hierarchy, but by adding `<exclusion>` you can simply resolve the conflict.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring-boot actuator, only exclusion of spring-logging might not help.
You will have to provide logging for it. Spring Boot support log4j for logging configuration.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Refrence: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.logging